# Parsing streaming JSON and handle "invalid" errors (with Oboe.js)

Tags: javascript, json, stream

I have a JSON file that is being appended continuously until it is finished (it contains coordinates from a simulation; while this simulation is running, the coordinates of each timeframe are appended to the JSON file).

In my webpage, these coordinates must be shown as soon as the simulation starts. To do this I'm using [Oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/examples#extracting-objects-from-the-json-stream) to display the coordinates as soon as they are present in the JSON file:

```
function smashIt(path){
        oboe(path)
                .node('frames.*', function( frame ){
                  animationFrames.push(frame);                    
                })
                .fail( function( errorReport ){
                    console.log(errorReport);
                    smashIt(path);
                })
                .done(function(finalObj){
                  finalObject = finalObj;
                  console.log(finalObj);
               });
}
```

The issue with this is that, since it's basically a **JSON stream** until the file is completely finished, the JSON might not be valid when the Oboe function has reached the end of the already available content: it may lack a `}` or comma to make the JSON valid.
If this happens, an error will be thrown by Oboe which I catch in the `.fail`-event. After logging the error I run the entire Oboe-function again, and eventually after about 50 `.fail()`'s the stream will have finished and I will eventually have the entire JSON object.

But this is a bad approach. The current functionality works to display the coordinates when they are being streamed already, but on each relaunch of the `smashIt()`-function the `.node()`-event will provide all the JSON nodes from the JSON file until that point (there will always be around 50-100 more since the previous `smashIt()` execution.

What I'm looking for is a way to handle invalid JSON errors and to let the Oboe `.node()`-method wait (or a better idea?) until the JSON **is valid** instead of having to use the `.fail`-approach; thus using only one `smashIt()` execution in which invalid JSON errors are properly handled.
I hoped Oboe.js would handle this by itself, but it appears not.

Comment: It seems like Oboe does need the file that it's fetching to be a complete and valid JSON file. What Oboe does is that it can start processing JSON even as it is trickling in because, for instance, you're on a slow connection. Maybe there is a way to set up a stream directly from Oboe to your simlautor, perhaps with a proxy inbetween. If it's possible to wait for the simulation, try that, it seems far easier.

Comment: It is indeed far easier to wait for the simulation, but it takes way too long. The reason I'm trying the streaming approach is to be able to see the "progress", because some simulations can take several minutes before it is finished.

Answer (score 2):

To get streaming, the absolute simplest approach that I can think of is that you poll the JSON file with XMLHTTPRequest.

You're going to have to deal with the incomplete JSON. Maye you can easily detect entry boundaries and do some custom parsing to get the partial data.

An improvement would be to only fetch new parts of the file. You can consider using the HTTP `Range` header or have a server side script that will return contents starting from an offset.

An further improvement would be to ditch the XMLHTTPRequest poll model and use WebSockets or ServerSentEvents to implement a push model. You can do this with a simple daemon that periodically reads the JSON file or maybe you can even write a daemon that hooks directly into your simulator [software engineering intensifies].